# I cannot create a new activity in eclipse project

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, google-play-services

Since I've installed google play services libray if I create a new  project src folder is empty and it's impossible to create a new activity, it doesn't appear, somebody knows what's happening??

Comment: Mine doesn't work either.. Bet ya it's a conspiracy to make us change to Android Studio!